# Not able to set up https site with port 443.rsa server certificate commonname (cn) does not match server name in SSl erroe log

Tags: ssl, apache2

I am using WAMP 2.0 with apache 2.2.11 on windows server 2008 R2.I am setting up only one domain on this WAMP server.
i have converted the .pfx file and extracted .crt and .key file using openSSL.
In the conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf, i have made following changes

SSLEngine on

```
<VirtualHost 162.62.90.11:443>
ServerAdmin webadmin@oursite.com
DocumentRoot "D:/webpages"
ServerName www.oursite.com

ErrorLog "logs/SSLerror.log"
CustomLog "logs/SSLaccess.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

SSLCertificateFile "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.11/conf/server.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.11/conf/server.key"

i checked in command prompt with httpd -t and i get syntax Ok.
But when i open the site with prefix https it does not open. In the error log it shows RSA certificate common name not matching with server name.

i tried replacing  the IP address in virtual host with  server name in certificate and the one in error log. Still it does not work.

It seems i'm missing something. Plz help me in rectifying this.
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i re did the whole thing , i found https site was acessible from same webserver with prefix https.
i checked through telnet if i could connect from another domain PC
but couldn't connect.
Firewall was blocking inbound connection for port 443.added an exception  and is working fine
Relieved now

Thanks to all who took time to respond and guide.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the port 443. For example,

```
**   <VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:443>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html2
ServerName www.yourdomain.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost> **
```

Comment: yeah i have opened the port 443 in virtual host tag. But still it does not work

Comment: [link](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-fix-common-ssl-errors.htm) check this site it will help you. I think your CSR wrong or mismatch, you need to re-generate again.